# Spark-Submit - Waiting (TaskSchedulerImpl : Initial job not accepted)

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, pyspark

**Intro**

I have created a small Spark cluster on AWS.
Master is a t2.small (1 core, 1gb RAM) on-demand server, 1 worker is a spot instance m5.2xlarge (48 VCPU, 30GB RAM)

Spark version 2.2.1, with aws-java-sdk-1.7.4

spark-defaults.conf:

`spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem`

master spark-env.sh:

`export SPARK_MASTER_HOST=10.0.129.94
export SPARK_WORKER_PORT=7080`

worker spark-env.sh:

`export SPARK_WORKER_PORT=7080`

Master Inbound Security Group:

[image: Master Security Group]

Worker Inbound Security Group:

[image]

Master private IP: 10.0.129.94 (SparkMaster hostname)

Worker private IP: 10.0.129.210 (SparkSlave hostname)

Spark Submit commmand:

`spark-submit --jars /home/torqmo/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/commons-cli-1.2.jar,/home/torqmo/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/hadoop-common-2.7.3.jar,/home/torqmo/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.3.jar,/home/torqmo/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar,/home/torqmo/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar --master spark://SparkMaster:7077 --executor-memory 2G --executor-cores 3 converter/convert.py --from-hour /2018/01/17/15/`

ps aux master:

`torqmo   22170  0.3  8.5 3033396 174428 ?      Sl   10:34   0:09 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -cp /home/torqmo/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/:/home/torqmo/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/* -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --host 10.0.129.94 --port 7077 --webui-port 8080`

ps aux worker:

`torqmo    6043  0.2  1.6 6767740 536740 ?      Sl   10:32   0:07 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -cp /home/torqmo/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/:/home/torqmo/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/* -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 --port 7080 spark://SparkMaster:7077`

**Problem**

I'm just trying to give it a pyspark script that converts JSON files in one bucket into Parquet to another bucket.

I've checked firewall access via telnet for both sides, and been referencing this documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html#configuring-ports-for-network-security

Everything is fine network wise, telnet shows ports are open properly.

Master Web UI and Worker UI are all showing available resources, they are not all occupied, I see ALIVE worker, I see running job, no stderr on Worker UI, yet I get this waiting state...

How do I debug it further? I see so many threads here regarding this issue, but after checking a dozen - they are all not my case.

Appreciate any help!